# What would you call someone who rather not have something than have it with bad sides?

Tags: single-word-requests

I wondered this when I was thinking about relationships but could apply to other situations. Let's say someone has a troubled relationship with their siblings so they'd rather not have them than put up with them. Or they ended up with a pet but they'd rather not have it and not deal with its responsibilities. Or they are assigned a project with good prospects but wouldn't want to do it because of risks.

I was thinking more of *apathetic* than *slothful*. I thought *picky* or *idealist* but they're not quite right.

Comment: A picky eater..

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like **all-or-nothing thinking**. According to [an article from the Cognitive Behavioral Therapy Los Angeles blog](https://cogbtherapy.com/cbt-blog/cognitive-distortions-all-or-nothing-thinking),

> All-or-nothing thinking refers to thinking in extremes.

So, I would say that your character has an **all-or-nothing attitude**.

Comment: This is still a hypernym, but close enough here I think for an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is a person who ***can't be bothered to*** make the effort. One possible word is ***shirker***. The verb *to shirk* means:

> to avoid doing something difficult, or to avoid accepting responsibility for something
>
> - A good manager should never *shirk* difficult decisions. ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shirk?q=shirker#shirk__3))

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shirker) defines ***shirker*** as:

> someone who avoids something, especially work.